# Delete the least populated polygons

Tags: data-model

Here is the plan. I need to delete every metro's least populated census tracts (in terms of population density). To what extent? As to preserve 98% of the metro's total population. I don't know how to program. Is there any existing tools I can use?

Thanks everybody!!

S.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange!  What GIS software and version are you using?

Comment: I think you need to provide a significant more amount of details, area, city, location, software you have access too, data you own, etc.

Comment: I am using arcgis 10. the area is all metros in U.S. I have already had the 361 metros' Census tract population. To delete the least populated tracts, as long as it doesn't threaten 98% of the metro's total population.

Comment: Put it simply, I need to delete rural tracts! But the criteria stated above is something existed in literature. Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sort the data by increasing density and remove records until up to 2% of the population has been eliminated.  Here are the details if you're unfamiliar with this kind of analysis in ArcGIS:

1. **Compute population density** by dividing population by area.  (If you don't have areas, compute them.  It's best to use an equal-area projection, but for most cities the projection won't make much of a difference.)
2. **Export three columns** in a format readable by your favorite statistics or spreadsheet software: tract identifier, population, and density.
3. In your stats/spreadsheet software, **sort the records** by increasing density.
4. **Compute the cumulative population**: that is, starting with a previous population of zero, add the current population to the previous population.
5. **Normalize the cumulative populations**: divide them by the total population (found as the very last cumulative population).
6. **Delete** all records where this fraction is 1 - 98/100 = 0.02 or less.
7. **Save the result** in a format ArcGIS can read.
8. Back in ArcGIS, **join the result to the original table** based on tract id.
9. **Use a definition query** or a special symbol in the map to eliminate the records having nothing joined to them.